# PHP for each, while loop, or ... similar

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I am looking for a way to execute some variables that I pass that will be incremented on a per line basis from a "textarea" box, though this question is not within the scope, however the intent is to write it so that whether its one, or over 100 lines that it accepts it as a single line to reference for database import and API extract on a per line basis, execute this.

so for each VARIABLE do this

variable will be needing to be receptive of just one in particular and will be stuck under an if else/case statement that is designating an alternate page like

```
page.php?apiid=SOMECODE&user=SOMEUSER&exec=add&do=this&do1=that
```

Where "do" is what these lines of code will have to be listening for, while I've come up with solutions - I've also caused some headache:

I've been using:

```
foreach($_GET AS $key => $value) {
     ${$key} = $value;
}
```

This `foreach` is nested before an `ifelse statement` where it grabs either API if something doesn't exist or hits my database (cache)...

But as you can see, this grabs *everything* ...  I'm trying guys, so I do appreciate your assistance, and will continue my search and adjust my post as necessary.

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question completely - I'm having a very hard time to understand the problem you're describing.

Comment: Unclear of what you are asking

Comment: Please just see this link: https://ac.trak-m.com/core/vinaudit.php?exec=in&vin=1HGCS127X8A018486&vin2=1HGCS2B84AA002555 You will see that there are two distinctive vins there, but there are 3 variables so the code is executed 3 times, the for each clause is before the if statement, the intent is to have several vins sent to the code, unless there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Am I still unclear? :)

Comment: I guess I need more coffee to get this!

Comment: So you just want to grab vin1 and vin2 and so on vin* and then fetch value for that those vin? Also how can I know I've to take only vin variables and not exec, like In url you have given because there is no relation there in url, or the variables are related to filename like vinaudit.php and hence process all vin*

Comment: @boom_Shiva To keep it simple, yes looking to extract the vin, I see that the rest of the if statement has to contend/flow with the foreach as the VIN in the if statement(s) aren't accepting the alteration of vinX (where X is the continuation per variable) ... oh, frustration kills the soul

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact relation you need to use, to check what variable you want to process from URL, but like for the current URL, if you want to make db requests for only `vin` variables and not others you can use the following logic:

```
if(!empty($_GET)){
 foreach( $_GET as $key => $val ){
   if(strpos('vin', $key) !== FALSE ){
      if(!empty($val)){
       $$key = htmlspecialchars($val);
         //perform your operation
      }
   }

 }//End of foreach
}
```

But this may be harmful to you, if someone is attacking server and posting a large number of such values in $_GET request.

Maybe you can explain proper logic for those variables in URL and there might be a better solution.

Comment: I pretty much came to the conclusion that what I was trying do was only complicating what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: So how would you go for it?